# File size handling in client side before passing it to server side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to validate file size in client side. The code below only handles success. I want to handle file size as well. Currently 500 (Internal Server Error) comes back behind the scene if the file is greater than 2MB.

Is there a way of manually handling it and setting error to "Max file size should be 2MB"?

Thanks in advance

Note: Code below is part of AngularJS

```
file.upload(url, function(data) {
    if(data.success !== true) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.design.pdf.status = '';
            $scope.errors.pdf = data.data;
        });
        return;
    }
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.design.pdf = {
            status: 'uploaded',
            file: data.data.name,
            name: data.data.original,
            size: data.data.size
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this file upload component. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. It can be done but is browser dependent.

Comment: Cross browsers solutions are a must nowadays.

Comment: It is a cross browser solution in that it handles browsers that don't support the FileReader component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use an `input type='file'` button.
You can create a directive that will bind to the button when it changes and get the size.

The directive :

```
app.directive('customUpload', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('change', function(){
          //size in bytes
          var size = element[0].files[0].size;
          console.log(size);
          //do something with the file
        });
      }
    };
});
```

And the html :

```
<input type='file' custom-upload>
```

Here is all the code in a plunker : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/GB6MFOWMbjOA7obFBq83?p=preview

Comment: Thanks I did some changes according to your example.